# Most effective way to build box shadows with CSS

Tags: css

I'm interested to find which way of creating box shadows with css is most effective. But that I mean : ease of implementation, flexibility, and cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onion skinning is my personal favorite.

An example can be found in this [alistapart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/onionskin/).

Answer (score 0):

This is now very simple to achieve:

```
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
```

First value is the horizontal offset.
Second value is vertical offset.
Third value is spread of blur effect.
Fourth Value is color.

Additionally, you can add another value of `inset`, which will make the shadow appear on the inside of you block element:

```
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.33) inset;
```

This is now very well supported: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Answer (score -1):

The way I find most effective currently is this:

The CSS rules needed :

```
    .shadow{
      position:relative;
      display:block;
      background-color:#bbb;
      border:1px solid black;
    }

    .shadowed_item{
        position:relative;
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:white;
        top:-5px;
        left:-5px;
    }
```

HTML code on which the CSS is applied:

```
<div class='shadow'>
    <div class='shadowed_item'>I have a shadow.</div>
</div>
```

I found it very simple to implement, flexible and it works the same on FF 3, IE 6 & 7.